# Spring - 'No matching factory method found' for entityManagerFactory error after adding AOP to the project

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

I have the following eof bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("....repositories")
public class JpaConfig {
    ...
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                       JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter,
                                                                       Properties jpaProperties) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("....entities");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
}
```

And it works perfect (even with declared aop dependencies) until I add an aspect to my project. After marking the aspect as a component I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [.../configs/JpaConfig.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'jpaConfig'; factory method 'entityManagerFactory()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
```

Here's my Maven dependencies:

```
    <!--AOP-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Data-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Database-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1208.jre7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Will provide additional information on request. Thank you very much.

**Update**
Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TestAspect {
    @Before("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Public Method invoked");
    }
}
```

**Update**
What's interesting is that this aspect works and prints test strings.

Comment: Post your aspect, too.

Comment: @AliDehghani Done.

Comment: The bottom line is, try to narrow down each aspect scope. If you fail to do that, you may get these surprising results

Comment: @AliDehghani Thank you. If I understood that correct, the problem occurs when spring tries to decorate eof.

Comment: Yeah..And even if it could decorate the eof successfully, you probably would see another failure in somewhere else, like the linked question does that on sub-classing a `final` class.